# why this query is faling?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

```
select max( sum(duration) ),cd from rent group by cd;
```

.

ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: Because you have nothing to group?

Comment: This kind of grouping is not at all proper by any means, check mysql documentation the results you'd get can even cross all the limit of expectations , only group by a field which is used in the aggregate function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From documentation - *group (aggregate) functions that operate on sets of values.*. SUM returns scalar value.

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT MAX(duration_sum_by_cd) FROM (
  SELECT SUM(duration) duration_sum_by_cd FROM rent 
    GROUP BY cd; 
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

that query is very broken. firstly, i don't think you can put a max around sum... 2nd you are grouping on a column "cd" which isn't in the selected columns.

I suggest doing some/many tutorials from [here](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/)

Comment: -1 You can group on CD, just that you cannot max on a SUM, because SUM outputs a single value.

Comment: why did you vote down? the guys query was previously `select max( sum(duration) ) from rent group by cd;` it had no cd in select...

Comment: Yes, that's why I voted down! you **can** do a group on CD, even if there is no CD in your select. So your answer is incorrect.